# Table row colour change on checkbox and when selected from MySQL

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple JavaScript that when a checkbox is selected then the row color changes. This works well.

However, when a user needs to edit their details they can see the boxes that they have checked (form the MySQL select) however the color has not changed, as the row color only changes when the user un-selects and then re-selects the checkboxes.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Below is the simple JavaScript

```
function ClickMakeColor(chk,ctrl)
{
    if(chk.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById(ctrl).className = 'CheckBoxOn';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(ctrl).className = 'CheckBoxOff';
    }
}
```

Comment: So set the class when you render the table....

Comment: For the record, you can replace your whole `if/else` statement with this : `document.getElementById(ctrl).className = chk.checked ? 'CheckBoxOn' : 'CheckBoxOff'`

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.

Sadly that did not work.

I think the problem is with the checkbox. Should I be changing that?

Thanks

<input type="checkbox" '. $Checked .' name="'. $set_col['DbName'] .'" id="WhoCanSee'. $ii .'" value="Yes" OnClick="ClickMakeColor(this,\'tr'. $ii .'\');">

Comment: Hi.  I don't know how to add a listening consul. All I have is a simple form with the onClick.  Do I need to change the onClick?

Comment: All sorted.  Found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) to toggle classes on/off. You didn't provide too much information such as `html` or what `ctrl` is, so there isn't much more info that can be given. If you update your question with that, I can give a better answer.

```
function ClickMakeColor(chk,ctrl) {
    let cl = document.getElementById(ctrl).classList
    cl.toggle('CheckBoxOn', chk.checked)
    cl.toggle('CheckBoxOff', !chk.checked)
}
```